# Expansion of the infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light, superposition, eigenvalue, observables

I was studying the expectation value of the energy of a particle in the groud state of the infinite square well after its expansion in terms of width (from $a$ to $2a$), which is:

$$\langle H\rangle= \int \Psi^* \hat H \Psi dx = \frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{a} \sin \left(x\frac{\pi}{a}\right) \hat H \sin \left(x\frac{\pi}{a}\right) dx = \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2ma^2}$$

Notice that

> the expectation value of H is independent of time; this is a
>   manifestation of conservation of energy in quantum mechanics (see
>   Griffiths; second edition; page 37).

*This means that the expectation value of the energy does not change after the expansion.*

I have been thinking about why does this happen and I just can think of instantaneous expansion. However this argument goes against the statement that **no-random information cannot travel faster than light.** Therefore, should I regard a random expansion instead of determining one?

If I am wrong in my argument, what am I missing?

**EDIT**

Due to the disagreement on the provided answer (**which I claim it has to be time-independent**) I will explain myself better and try to write down all the necessary steps.

Let's focus on what is the most probable result for the energy. We know that:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}|c_n|^2 = 1$$

So the approach I will use is based on getting the constant $c_n$, plug into it different values of $n$ and take the square of the yielded number.

We can always write down the initial wave function as a linear combination of stationary states:

$$\Psi (x, 0) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n \psi_n (x)$$

Of course, this is always the case if $\psi_n$ is a *complete* set of functions.

Let's now multiply both sides by $\psi_m^*$ and integrate.

$$\int \psi_m^*\Psi (x, 0) dx= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n \int \psi_m \psi_n^*(x) dx= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n \delta_{mn}$$

If $m = n$ (i.e exploiting the orthonormality of the stationary states) we get:

$$c_n =  \int \psi_n^*\Psi (x, 0) dx$$

This method for getting the coefficients is known as the **Fourier's trick**.

OK, once here we just have to use the Fourier's trick on our problem:

$$c_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a} \int_0^{a} sin ( \frac{x\pi}{a}) sin ( \frac{n x\pi}{2a})dx$$

Where:

$$\Psi (x, 0) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}sin ( \frac{x\pi}{a})$$

$$\psi_n^* = \sqrt{\frac{2}{2a}}sin ( \frac{n x\pi}{2a})$$

Note that the stationary states for the infinite square well are real so it would not be necessary to use *.

Good; now if we solve the integral we get:

If **n** is even (except for n = 2):

$$c_n = 0$$

If **n** is odd:

$$c_n = \pm \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{\pi(n^2-4)}$$

As pointed out, **n = 2** is not included in this solution so we get it separately:

$$c_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a} \int_0^{a} sin ( \frac{x\pi}{a}) sin ( \frac{2 x\pi}{2a})dx = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a} \int_0^{a} sin^2 ( \frac{x\pi}{a}) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

If we want to get the probabilities we just have to square the three results obtained.

So clearly we see that the most probable outcome is associated with **n = 2**, so the most probable value for the energy will be:

$$E_2 = \frac{(2)^2 \pi^2 \hbar^2}{8ma^2} = \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2ma^2}$$

**Which is the same value than before the expansion of the well occurred.**

**Here comes the key of the problem:**

I had the following idea before performing any calculations: if the most probable value for the energy after the expansion of the well **is the same** than before the expansion, the expectation value should yield the same result as well.

And that is indeed what happens:

$$\langle H\rangle= \int \Psi^* \hat H \Psi dx = \frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{a} \sin \left(x\frac{\pi}{a}\right) \hat H \sin \left(x\frac{\pi}{a}\right) dx = \frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2ma^2}$$

**PS:** My original question was totally conceptual. However, I can post another question focusing on that and let this one to discuss the solving method.

Comment: Why do you think that the expectation value does not depend on $a$? The formula for the expectation value you gave has an explicit dependency on it...

Comment: I did not mean that it does not depend on a. I meant that it does not change its value after the expansion

Comment: You are really overly worried when you try to make sense of the "instantaneous" expansion of the well.  This is just a drummed up problem to identify the initial state of the bigger well.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I am overthinking about how non-random instantaneous expansion of the well is even possible...

Comment: @JD_PM If the instantaneous expansion is throwing you off, instead just think of an expansion that is "fast enough"

Comment: Please, may you reopen the question? (I have read that posting a message is the way to proceed so as to get your question reopened).